# How do options work?

Tags: ml

This is a simple function to find the maximum int in a list, but I'm confused by how the options are working:

```
(* fn : int list -> int option *)
fun max1 (xs : int list) =
    if null xs then NONE
    else
        let val tl_ans = max1 (tl xs)
        in
            if isSome tl_ans andalso valOf tl_ans > hd xs
            then tl_ans
            else SOME (hd xs)
        end
```

It is using ML "options", but I don't know how. The first **NONE** use seems straightforward, but the later use with **isSome** and **valOf** seem to be coming out of nowhere. I sort of understand that the **SOME** is putting **(hd xs)** in its type, but I cannot fathom how this

```
 if isSome tl_ans andalso valOf tl_ans > hd xs
```

is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tl_ans` will have type `int option`, since it is defined to be the result of applying `max1` to `tl xs`. If `isSome tl_ans` is `true`, then that means `tl_ans` = `SOME (valOf tl_ans)`, so we can get the `SOME`-wrapped value from `tl_ans` with `valOf` (but again, only when we already know it's a `SOME`, which is why we need that `isSome` call there).

A much cleaner way to write that is to use pattern matching, both for the list and for the `option` value:

```
fun max1 (xs : int list) =
    case xs 
     of [] => NONE
      | x::rest => case max1 rest 
                    of NONE => SOME x
                     | SOME max => if maxRest > x then SOME maxRest else SOME x
```

The neat thing about writing it this way, is that it leaves no room for the kind of error where you use `valOf` without first ensuring, by checking `isSome`, that it can be used.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I finally realized my confusion came from the recursion happening in the let binding: let val tl_ans = max1 (tl xs) . I wasn't properly seeing the recursion taking precedence over the body of let. Without that understanding I was wondering how tl_ans had become type option.